# Populate rows with date by date on DataTable

Tags: c#, database, linq, datatable, row

I got a DataTable and a row like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|   date   |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
--------------------------------------------
|     x    |  200  |  30   |   5   |   7   |
--------------------------------------------
```

And this code which add up every number from past to present:

```
var topla = Dao.Sum<x>(a => (a.Orj_Fiyat_VergiDahil * a.Ana_Miktar * a.Kur) - a.Iskonto_Tutar, a => (urunidler.Contains(a.Urun_Id)));
```

A, b, c and d are categories for each item. And row shows us their sales from first sale to last sale. So i sold 200$ "a" item from my start to today. But I want to populate this datatable like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|   date   |   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
--------------------------------------------
| 24.12.18 |  100  |  10   |   2   |   1   |
--------------------------------------------
| 25.12.18 |  50   |  5    |   1   |   1   |
--------------------------------------------
| 26.12.18 |  1    |  3    |   2   |   1   |
--------------------------------------------
```

(Numbers are example)

How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable Dao = new DataTable();

            var groups = Dao.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("date").Date).ToList();

            DataTable sumTable = Dao.Clone();
            int numberOfColumns = sumTable.Columns.Count;

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = sumTable.Rows.Add();
                newRow["date"] = group.Key;

                for (int col = 1; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                {
                    newRow[col] = group.Sum(x => (int)x[col]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```